# ¿Como hago para que sepa cual correo existe o cual no?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
   <?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "contrumeca");

if($_POST)
{
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$pregunta = $_POST['pregunta'];


$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios_noadministradores WHERE correo = '{$correo}' AND pregunta = '{$pregunta}'") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

$count = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($consulta))
{
   $response["success"] = true;
   $response["correo"] = $correo;
   $response["pregunta"] = $pregunta;

   if($count>0) 
   {

   require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';

   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

   try {

   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;   
   $mail->isSMTP();   
   $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";  
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = 'contrumeca.ca@gmail.com';
   $mail->Password = '25408448g';
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
   $mail->Port = 587;



   $mail->setFrom('contrumeca.ca@gmail.com', 'Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A');
   $mail->addAddress($correo, $correo);                


   $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
   $mail->Subject = 'Recuperación de Contraseña';
   $mail->Body    = 'Prueba';
   $mail->AltBody = 'Prueba';

   $mail->send();
   echo 'El correo ha sido enviado correctamente';
   } catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "El correo no pudo ser enviado: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
   }


   }else{echo 'Correo no existe';}


   }

   echo json_encode($response);


}



?>

<html>

<body>

   <form method = "POST">

    Email: <input type="correo" name = "correo">
    <br>   <br>
    Pregunta: <input type="text" name = "pregunta" id = "pregunta">
    <input type="submit">

   </form> 

</body>

</html>
```

Pasa lo siguiente: Cree unos input en html para ver cual era el verdadero error que me arrojaba, y para mi sorpresa si era lo que ya sabia que era, lo cual solucione, cuando envio un correo que en la BDD existe el lo envia, pero cuando no, no lo envia, dice correo no existe, PERO, en Android Studio (estoy haciendo una app) siempre aunque vaya lleno, vacio, correo invalido o no, dice que fue enviado inclusive si el correo no existe, entonces, de verdad, tengo horas y dias con esto, y no he logrado conseguir el error con todas las formas que he investigado para solucionarlo, entonces decidi preguntarles a ustedes.

Adjunto el codigo Android:

```
   package com.example.proyectoconstruccionesmetalurgicas;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Gravity;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
        import com.android.volley.Request;
        import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
        import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
        import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

        public class Recuperar_Contrasena extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView texto_1, texto_2;
        ImageView icono_empresa;
        EditText correo_electronico, pregunta;
        Button Enviar_Correo;
        RequestQueue requestQueue;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recuperar__contrasena);

        //*Declaramos los identificadores *//

        texto_1 = findViewById(R.id.texto_1);
        texto_2 = findViewById(R.id.texto_2);
        icono_empresa = findViewById(R.id.logo_empresa);
        correo_electronico = findViewById(R.id.correo_electronico);
        pregunta = findViewById(R.id.et_pregunta);
        Enviar_Correo = findViewById(R.id.Enviar_Correo);

        Enviar_Correo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             enviarContrasena("http://192.168.1.108/Recuperar_Contrasena.php");

            }
        });


        }
                private void enviarContrasena(String URL) {
                        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correo no fue enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                        mostrarToast("Correo enviado");


                                }
                        }) {
                                @Override
                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                                        //*Enviar parametros al servidor *//

                                        Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();

                                        parametros.put("correo", correo_electronico.getText().toString());
                                        parametros.put("pregunta", pregunta.getText().toString());

                                        return parametros;
                                }
                        };

                        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

                }

                private void mostrarToast (String texto)
                {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_correo_enviado,
                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_correoenviado));

                        TextView textView = layout.findViewById(R.id.texto_1);
                        textView.setText(texto);

                        ImageView imageView = layout.findViewById(R.id.correo);

                        Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(R.drawable.correo_enviado).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(imageView);

                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 200);
                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();

                }

                private void mostrarToast2 (String texto)
                {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_correo_noenviado,
                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_correo_no_enviado));

                        TextView textView = layout.findViewById(R.id.texto_1);
                        textView.setText(texto);

                        ImageView imageView = layout.findViewById(R.id.correo_icono);

                        Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(R.drawable.correo).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(imageView);

                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 200);
                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();

                }

                public void limpiar ()
                {
                        correo_electronico.setText("");
                        pregunta.setText("");
                }
        }
```

Claro, por alli encontre de que tengo que enviar las condiciones establecidas lo cual estoy intentando hacer pero no me da tampoco, que me recomiendan gente hacer???

AYUDA!!!

Comment: Tienes muchos errores de lógica en tu código PHP y en tu código Android. Debes saber que **Android debería esperar una sola salida desde el código PHP, no varias**. Tú tienes varios `echo` en el PHP, no vas controlando nada, vas haciendo `echo` como si estuvieras mostrando datos en un cliente HTML. Para ser breve, deberías ir controlando el código PHP y metiendo las posibles respuestas en un array y luego, al final, imprimir ese array como un JSON. Luego en Android recibes esa única respuesta, lo conviertes a JSON y determinas lo que haya ocurrido. Para este caso, yo pondría una clave...

Comment: ... `status` en el JSON con un valor `success` o `fail` por ejemplo, en caso de que haya habido error o éxito y en base a eso mostrar un mensaje o hacer otra cosa. No sé si me entiendes, se trata de sincronizar tu código entre PHP y Android, respondiendo un JSON con alguna clave desde la cual puedas determinar lo que haya ocurrido. En el PHP hay otros errores de lógica, por ejemplo, no puedes pasar a recorrer los resultados con el `while` antes de verificar la cantidad de filas obtenidas, debes comprobar primero si hay filas e ir controlando las salidas con un array como ya dije.